# Simplificación de multiplicación de polinomios

Tags: python, matemáticas

Soy relativamente nuevo programando y como proyecto personal decidí hacer una calculadora de operaciones básicas de polinomios (Suma, Multiplicaicón, Resta y División) sin ayuda de librerías en Python, actualmente estoy atorado en el paso final para la Multiplicación; simplificación.
La "L1" representa el exponente de la "x" y la "L2" representa el coeficiente de la "x".

```
L1 = [4,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,0]
L2 = [2,3,2,4,6,4,6,9,6]
```

El resultado esperado para este ejemplo sería terminar con las siguientes listas:

```
L4 = [4,3,2,1,0]
L5 = [2,7,14,13,6]
```

Lo que necesito es encontrar un método para sumar cada elemento de la L2 que corresponda a cada elemento de la L1 repetido, o sea, en caso de los exponentes 2:

```
L6 = [2,2,2]
L7 = [2,6,6]
```

Una disculpa si no es muy clara mi pregunta, es la primera publicación que hago en un foro.
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución sin usar ninguna librería ni función. Es el mismo algoritmo de abulafia en versión trabajosa:

```
def simplificar(L1, L2):
    resultado = dict()
    for i in range(len(L1)):
        key = L1[i]
        if not key in resultado:
            resultado[key] = 0
        resultado[key] += L2[i]

    return list(resultado.keys()), list(resultado.values())
```

**Demo**

```
exp = [4,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,0]
coef = [2,3,2,4,6,4,6,9,6]

L3, L4 = simplificar(exp, coef)
print(L3)
print(L4)
```

produce:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 7, 14, 13, 6]
```

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta es la que voy a implementar al programa final, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Una solución sencilla. Emparejas las listas `L1` y `L2` (que han de ser de la misma longitud) con la función `zip()` para así ir tomando pares de valores (uno de cada lista). El primer valor en cada par sería el exponente y el segundo sería el coeficiente. Usas el exponente como clave de un diccionario para ir sumando el coeficiente a lo que ya hubiera en esa clave del diccionario.

Si además usas el tipo `defaultdict(int)` (un diccionario cuyos valores se crean con el valor cero por defecto en el momento en que son accedidos por primera vez, si no existían ya), la cosa queda muy simple:

```
from collections import defaultdict

p = defaultdict(int)
for exp, coef in zip(L1, L2):
  p[exp] += coef
```

El resultado en `p` es un diccionario en el que cada clave es cada uno de los exponentes procesados, y cada valor es el resultado de sumar los coeficientes. En tu ejemplo este diccionario tendría:

```
{0: 6, 1: 13, 2: 14, 3: 7, 4: 2}
```

Si quieres tenerlo en dos listas separadas (una para exponentes y otra para coeficientes), de mayor a menor exponente, puedes separarlos así:

```
L4 = list(sorted(p, reverse=True))
L5 = [p[exp] for exp in L4]
```

Y se obtiene:

```
L4: [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
L5: [2, 7, 14, 13, 6]
```

### Sin usar defaultdict

El código queda un poco más largo pues hay que verificar que la clave exista en el diccionario (y si no crearla antes de acceder a ella):

```
p = {}
for exp, coef in zip(L1, L2):
  if not exp in p:
    p[exp] = 0
  p[exp]+=coef
```

La forma de separar el resultado en dos listas sería la misma.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si te molesta el usar `defaultdict` (que no requiere librerías externas, sino que viene en la librería estándar) lo puedes hacer de todas formas con un diccionario normal, pero entonces tendrás que mirar si la clave ya estaba en él o no, para asignarle un cero si no estaba

Comment: Creo que lo mejor es usar el defaultdict, se ve como una buena forma de ahorrar tiempo, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1):

Otra idea, sería plantear el polinomio, como una lista simple, donde los elementos de la lista son los coeficientes y la posición dentro de la lista es el exponente, así l = [4,-4,0] corresponde al polinomio 4x^2-4x=0, el grado del polinomio corresponde a len(l)-1, es decir, en este caso 2. Así las operaciones podrías realizarlas por posición dentro de las listas. Hay que tener en cuenta que para polinomios incompletos en la posición de la lista deberías rellanarlo con el coeficiente 0.

Comment: Esa es una buena idea para almacenar el polinomio en su fase "final", una vez agrupados términos, si no hay muchos términos ausentes. No es una representación densa si el polinomio tiene un grado muy alto pero muchos coeficientes iguales a cero

Comment: Eso sí, para un polinomio x^100=0, necesitamos una lista de 101 elementos, con 101 elementos, 100 de los cuales serían 0. Aunque veo esta representación más lógica.

Comment: Es una representación útil cuando el mismo polinomio debe ocuparse una y otra vez, ya que minimiza el tiempo necesario para recuperar un coeficiente.